# llvm alloca dependencies

Tags: llvm

I am trying to determine for certain Load instructions from my pass their corresponding Alloca instructions (that can be in other previous blocks). The chain can be something like : `TargetLoad(var) -> other stores/loads that use var (or dependencies on var) -> alloca(var).` , linked on several basic blocks. Do you know how can I do it?

I tried to use the methods from DependenceAnalysis and MemoryDependenceAnalysis, but the results were not correct. For instance, `MemoryDependenceAnalysis::getDependency` should be good with option "Def", but works only for stores, not for loads. Also I have a segfault when trying to use `MemoryDependenceAnalysis::getNonLocalPointerDependency` or `MemoryDependenceAnalysis::getPointerDependencyFrom` . When I try to check my result using MemDepResult::getDef(), the result for Load instructions is the same instruction ! So its depending on itself, that being weird since it is using a variable that is previously defined in the code.

The alternative of making the intersection for identifying common parts between all the variables used by target_load_instructions and all the allocated variables is not an option. Because there might be something like : `alloca(a) ... c=a*b+4 .... load(c)`.

It seems also that DependenceAnalysis::depends() is not ok for my pass. The next line of code is only for reference: `if(DA.depends(allocaInstrArray[i],loadInstrArray[j],true))` is always false. And it should be true in several cases. I think I am not using it correctly.

However, I made the assumption that maybe depends() does not work for Alloca. So I checked the dependencies among all Load instructions kept in an array. Some results are not based on the loaded variable as they should. For example: `LOAD   %3 = load i32* %c, align 4 IS DEPENDENT ON  %1 = load i32* %j, align 4`. As you can see, one is loading c and one is loading j. In my Test.cpp target code there is no dependence between j and c. Maybe the dependence is not based on variables/memory locations used?

Thank you for any suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `getOperand(0)` or `getOperand(1)` of the ICMP instructions. If there is `isa<LoadInst>` valid, then cast them to `LoadInst`. `getPointerOperand()` will get the Value* that is the actual variable which is searched. 
Second, do the same procedure between Load instructions and `Alloca` instructions. `getOperand(0)` applied on Load gives the corresponding `Alloca` instruction.
Finally, link the two results together, by checking the dependencies.